# qrcode picture does not resize asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, qr-code

The code you see below creates a qrcode. In this code, I have specified the size of the generated image, but after creating the image, the size of the generated image is different from the size I specified, and the image is always generated in 1060x1060 pixels, but I want The photo on the site should be 150x150 pixels, please help

```
    protected string set_QrCode(string fileLink)
{
    FileUpload _fu = new FileUpload();
    string code = fileLink;
    QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(code, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    imgBarCode.Height = 150;
    imgBarCode.Width = 150;
    using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
            imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);


            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage));
            var filename = Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid()).Substring(0, 5) + Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid()).Substring(0, 5) + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("FFFFFF") + System.DateTime.Now.Minute + ".png";// +System.DateTime.Now.ToString("fffffffffff") + ".png";
            var file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/docs/certificates/" + filename);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, data);

            return "~/docs/certificates/" + filename;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You instantiate a 150x150 `WebControl.Image`, then you never use it. You should either resize the `Bitmap bitMap` or, better, tweak the `QRCodeGenerator` to be able to generate a specific size images (maybe adding an optional parameter to `CreateQrCode` method named `size`).

Comment: If you opt to resize the generated image (that would not the first choice I would made) you have [several similar questions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+resize+a+bitmap)